# IE 11 changing URL

Tags: url, internet-explorer-11

I am getting strange behaviour in IE 11. 
When I go to my web application using URL 
**"hostname:port/myapp-web/app/login.jsp"** 
The login page is displayed, And Login is done successfully.

Now. Problem is that, after logging in, App's landing page is index.html. 
So URL should be **"hostname:port/myapp-web/app/index.html"**

Instead, IE changes it to **"hostname:port///index.html"**

Now, when I try to do any other operation or navigation, it fails because base URL is changed and my JS code cannot find app context root and all AJAX calls fails.

I tried searching over internet for the same, but couldn;t find any answer.

Please help if anyone has idea about such behaviour.

P.S. App is working fine in IE: 8/9, Chrome and FF. 
I found something related to UTF-* character URLs but my app uses plain text URL with NO special characters.

App is developed using Spring for server side and KnockoutJS, HTML for UI.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```html
index.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=EDGE" />
    <!-- script includes -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NavigationBar -->
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();      // app.js
  
    $.getJSON('/myapp-web/Security/authorise', function (response) {
        
        app.common.navbar.reRenderNavBar(response);
        app.navigation = new Navigation("AdminHome");    // navigation.js
      
        // This navigation causes IE11 to change URL to http://host:port///#AdminHome
        // it should be // http://host:port/myapp-web/app/index.html#AdminHome
    });
  
</script>
</html>
```

```js
Navigation.js

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ")
var ieVer = -1;

if (msie > 0) {
    var ieVer = ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie));
    //console.log(ieVer);
}

var NavigationInput = function (pName, pValue) {
    this.paramName = pName;
    this.paramValue = pValue;
    this.toString = function () {
        return pName + ":" + pValue;
    }

}

var Navigation = function (startupView) {
    var self = this;

    this.navInput = [];
    this.navViewModel = null;
    this.navViewModelInitComplete = false;

//    this.navigate = function navigate(view) {
//
//        if (view !== this.currentView) {
//            self.loadView(view, true, null);
//        }
//    }

    this.navigateWithParams = function navigateWithParams(view, params) {
        self.loadView(view, true, params);
    }

    this.goBack = function goBack() {
        history.go(-1);
        //history.back();
    }

    this.loadView = function (view, pushHistory, params) {
        var contentframe = $("#content");
        //app.consolePrintInfo("navigation", "previous view: " + self.currentView + " new view: " + view);
        if (typeof (self.currentView) != 'undefined' && self.currentView
            && self.currentView.toLowerCase() == view.toLowerCase()
            && isParamsEqual(params)) {
            return;
        }


        var constructedView;


        constructedView = "Views/" + view + "/" + view + ".html"

        contentframe.load(constructedView, function () {
            self.currentView = view;

            modUrl = view;

            if (params != null) {
                if (params instanceof String) {
                    modUrl = params;
                }
                else {
                    var queryStr = self.convertParamsToQueryString(params);
                    modUrl += "?" + queryStr;
                }

//                if (typeof(app.navigation.navViewModel) != 'undefined'
//                    && app.navigation.navViewModel
//                    && !app.navigation.navViewModelInitComplete)
//                {
//                    app.navigation.navViewModelInitComplete = app.navigation.navViewModel.initViewModel(self.convertQueryStringToParams(modUrl));
//                }
            }

            if (pushHistory) {
                if (ieVer > 6) {
                    window.history.pushState(view, null, modUrl);
                }
                else {
                    window.history.pushState(view, null, "#" + modUrl);
                }
            }

            app.consolePrintInfo("navigation", "modified url:" + modUrl + " view model: " + app.navigation.navViewModel);
            var navInputs = self.convertQueryStringToParams(modUrl);
            self.urlInputs = navInputs;
            app.navigation.navViewModelInitComplete = app.navigation.navViewModel.initViewModel(navInputs);


            //$.getScript("Views/" + view + ".js", function () {
            //});
        });

        isParamsEqual = function (iParams) {
            if ((typeof(self.urlInputs) == 'undefined' || !self.urlInputs)
                && (typeof(iParams) == 'undefined' || !iParams)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (app.utility.isObjectNull(self.urlInputs) && app.utility.isObjectNull(iParams)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    this.convertParamsToQueryString = function (params) {
        var result = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                result += "&";
            }
            result += params[i].paramName + "=" +
                params[i].paramValue;

        }

        return result;
    };

    this.convertQueryStringToParams = function (modUrl) {
        var inputs = null;

        var fragments = modUrl.split("?");
        if (fragments && fragments.length == 2) {
            var f = fragments[1].split("&");
            if (f && f.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
                    var inp = f[i].split("=");
                    if (inputs == null) inputs = [];
                    inputs.push(new NavigationInput(inp[0], inp[1]));
                }
            }
        }

        return inputs;
    };

    this.back = function () {
        if (history.state) {
            var view = self.getView();
            self.loadView(view, false, self.convertQueryStringToParams(location.href));
        } else {
            var view = self.getView();
            self.loadView(view, true, self.convertQueryStringToParams(location.href));
        }
    };

    this.getView = function () {
        var fragments = location.href.split('#');
        if (fragments && fragments.length === 2) {
            var inFrag = fragments[1].split('?');
            if (inFrag && inFrag.length === 2) {
                return inFrag[0];
            }
            else {
                return fragments[1];
            }
        } else {
            return startupView;
        }
    };

    this.loadView(this.getView(), true, this.convertQueryStringToParams(location.href));
    $(window).on('popstate', self.back);
}
```

```js
app.js:
-----------------
app = {};

// utilities
app.utility = {};
app.ui = {};

// common
app.common = {};

// validation
app.validation = {};

// common components
app.common.navbar = {};
app.common.authorisation = {};


app.initialize = function () {

    $.blockUI.defaults.message = '<h4><img src="images/busy.gif" />&nbsp;Processing...</h4>';
    $.blockUI.defaults.css.border = '2px solid #e3e3e3';
    $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);

    //$(document).click(function() { $(".popover").remove(); });
}

app.consolePrintInfo = function (tag, message) {
    if (typeof(console) != 'undefined' && console)
        console.info(tag + ": " + message);
}

app.ui.showAppError = function (message) {
    app.consolePrintInfo("App", "displaying error message: " + message);
    $('#error-console').removeClass('app-error-console-hidden');
    $('#error-console').removeClass('alert-info');
    $('#error-console').addClass('alert-error');
    $('#error-console').html(message);
}

app.ui.showAppInfo = function (message) {
    app.consolePrintInfo("App", "displaying info message: " + message);
    $('#error-console').show();
    $('#error-console').removeClass('app-error-console-hidden');
    $('#error-console').removeClass('alert-error');
    $('#error-console').addClass('alert-info');
    $('#error-console').html(message);
    $('#error-console').fadeOut(4000);
}


app.utility.addQueryParameter = function (url, paramName, paramValue) {
    var rUrl = url;
    if (typeof(paramName) != 'undefined' && paramName
        && typeof(paramValue) != 'undefined' && paramValue) {

        if (rUrl.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            rUrl = rUrl + "&" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
        }
        else {
            rUrl = rUrl + "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
        }
    }
    return rUrl;
}

app.utility.addSearchParameter = function (paramName, paramValue) {
    var rValue = undefined;
    if (typeof(paramName) != 'undefined' && paramName
        && typeof(paramValue) != 'undefined' && paramValue) {
        rValue = paramName + ":" + paramValue;
    }
    return rValue;
}

app.utility.searchParameter = function (inputKeyArray, paramName) {
    if (inputKeyArray instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputKeyArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputKeyArray[i].paramName == paramName) {
                return inputKeyArray[i].paramValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

app.utility.isObjectNull = function (obj) {
    return typeof(obj) == 'undefined' || obj == undefined || !obj;
}

app.utility.isObjectNotNull = function (obj) {
    return typeof(obj) != 'undefined' && obj;
}

app.utility.isFunction = function (obj) {
    return !!(obj && obj.constructor && obj.call && obj.apply);
};

app.utility.parseError = function (em) {
    if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(em)) {
        jem = JSON.parse(em);
        var keyArray = new Array();
        keyArray.push(jem.errorCode);
        keyArray.push(jem.errorMessage);
        return keyArray;
    }
    else {
        return undefined;
    }

}

app.utility.showAppErrorDialog = function (errTitle, errMessage) {
    if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(errMessage)) {
        var $message = $("Error:" + errMessage)
            .dialog({autoOpen: false, width: 300, title: errTitle, modal: true, buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }}
        );
        $message.dialog('open');
    }
}

app.utility.showErrorDialog = function (err) {
    if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(err)) {
        var $message = $('<div><p>Unfortunately, there has been error in the server!</p><p>' + err[1] + '</p><p>Please send the screenshot to developer team</div>')
            .dialog({autoOpen: false, width: 300, title: err[0], modal: true, buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }}
        );
        $message.dialog('open');
    }
}

app.utility.showDialog = function (heading, text) {
    if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(heading) && !app.utility.isObjectNull(text)) {
        var $message = $('<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>')
            .dialog({autoOpen: false, width: 300, title: heading, modal: true, buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }}
        );
        $message.dialog('open');
    }
}

app.utility.populateToolTip = function () {
    $("img[id^='tooltip']").each(function () {
        var idName = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#' + idName).tooltip('toggle');
        $('#' + idName).tooltip('hide');

    });
};

app.utility.isNotEmptyNumberValue = function (input) {

    if (app.utility.isObjectNull(input)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!isNaN(input) && isFinite(input) && ("" + input).indexOf("-") == -1 && ("" + input).indexOf("e") == -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};

app.utility.isNotEmptyWholeNumberValue = function (input) {

    if (app.utility.isObjectNull(input)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!isNaN(input) && isFinite(input) &&
        ("" + input).indexOf("-") == -1 && ("" + input).indexOf(".") == -1 && ("" + input).indexOf("e") == -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};


app.utility.isNumberValue = function (input) {
    if (!isNaN(input) && isFinite(input)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};


app.utility.doHttpRequest = function (input) {

    if (app.utility.isObjectNull(input) || app.utility.isObjectNull(input.rURL)) {
        app.utility.showDialog("Error!", "Unable to find required inputs. Error in sending request");
        return false;
    }

    app.consolePrintInfo("HTTP REQUEST:  ", "[URL] :" + input.rURL);
    app.consolePrintInfo("HTTP REQUEST:  ", "[Type] :" + input.rType);
    app.consolePrintInfo("HTTP REQUEST:  ", "[Input] :" + input.rDataToSend);

    $.ajax({
        url: input.rURL,
        type: input.rType,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: false,
        data: input.rDataToSend,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function (response) {
        app.consolePrintInfo("HTTP REQUEST:  ", "[Output - success] :" + JSON.stringify(response));

        if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(input.rOnSuccessFunction)) {
            input.rOnSuccessFunction(response);
        }
        else if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(input.rOnSuccessMessage)) {
            app.utility.showDialog("Complete", input.rOnSuccessMessage);
        }
    }).error(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 401) {
            // session expired. redirect to login page.
            app.consolePrintInfo("HTTP REQUEST:  ", "[Output - failure] : Session Expired");
            var $message = $('<div><p>' + response.responseText + '</p></div>')
                .dialog({autoOpen: false, width: 300, title: 'Session Expired', modal: true, buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        // Remove the cached data
                        //comp_storage.remove("lastStoredValue");
                        //comp_storage.remove("permissionStr");
                        //window.open("/aid-web/logout", "_self");
                        app.utility.doLogout();
                    }
                }}
            );
            $message.dialog('open');
        }
        else if (response.status == 400) {
            app.consolePrintInfo("HTTP REQUEST:  ", "[Output - failure] : Server Error");
            var $message = $('<div><p>' + response.responseText + '</p></div>')
                .dialog({autoOpen: false, width: 300, title: 'Server Error', modal: true, buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }}
            );
            $message.dialog('open');
        }
        else {
            app.consolePrintInfo("HTTP REQUEST:  ", "[Output - failure] :" + response.responseText);

            if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(input.rOnErrorFunction)) {
                input.rOnErrorFunction(response.responseText);
            }
            else if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(input.rOnErrorMessage)) {
                app.utility.showDialog("Error", input.rOnErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    });

};

app.utility.doLogout = function () {
    comp_storage.remove("lastStoredValue");
    comp_storage.remove("permissionStr");
    window.open("/aid-web/logout", "_self");
};

// common
// Nav bar component

app.common.navbar.reRenderNavBar = function (content) {
    // [SAMPLE] To update the common component. create a view model of that
    // component. set the needed variables.
    // and *definately call applyBindings()*

    app.common.navbar.navBarViewModel = new ko.navBarComponent.viewModel({
        // set compt. values if needed. like below.
        //navBarComponent_isEmpty:ko.observable(false)
    });
    app.common.navbar.navBarViewModel.navBarComponent_reRender(content);
    ko.applyBindings(app.common.navbar.navBarViewModel, $('#nav-bar').get(0));
}

// Authorisation component
app.common.authorisation.storeRoleInfo = function (permissionArr) {
    comp_auth.storeRoleInfo(permissionArr);
};

app.common.authorisation.isRolePresent = function (roleName) {
    return comp_auth.isRolePresent(roleName);
};


// validation
app.validation.highlightElement = function (id, text) {

}

app.validation.highlightError = function (eleId, heading, text) {
    if (!app.utility.isObjectNull(heading) && !app.utility.isObjectNull(text) && !app.utility.isObjectNull(eleId)) {
        $("#" + eleId).addClass("ui-state-error");
        var $message = $('<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 300,
                title: heading, modal: true,
                close: function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        jQuery("#" + eleId).removeClass("ui-state-error");
                    }, 500);
                },
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            jQuery("#" + eleId).removeClass("ui-state-error");
                        }, 500);
                    }
                },
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.1,
                },

            }
        ).parent().addClass("ui-state-error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: When I tried using Emulation (through developer tools) for IE 8 and 9, my application worked as expected. URLs were properly redirected.
Sems its the issue with IE10 and IE 11.

Comment: Use [X-UA-Compatible metatag](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible) as a temporary fix to force IE10 and IE11 to use IE9 mode (best not make it permanent because it will mean your website misses out the better functionality). Without some more information about what is triggering the redirect I can really only take a stab in the dark as to what your issue is. Have you tried monitoring the traffic between the browser and server to see if there is any difference? Is it KnockoutJS that is meant to redirect to the app's landing page or is it being done server side?

Comment: Hi Adrian,
Thanks for responding. But My application already uses it.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=EDGE"/>

I've tried debugging all network and Ajax calls. All are working as expected.
When I manually type the correct URL after logging in the respective page renders properly. So it's definitely Bug in IE. Also, IE 10 has similar issue(I found few results when I tried Searching same issue with IE10)

Comment: OK what about the redirect after login. Where is that being applied? Server or Client?

Comment: Client. My application uses Spring's Form authentication. So on Successful Login, View for Index.html is returned. And then Index.html does AJAX call on OnLoad() to render Landing page ViewModel(KnockoutJS View Model).

Comment: So my app is Single page App, after Login, Index.html renders the respective Views based on Menu selection. so typpically the url would be like http://host:port/myapp-web/app/index.html#landingPage, http://host:port/myapp-web/app/index.html#Menu1Page and so on.

Comment: Any chance that you can post some bare minimum sample code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Added the sample code. but I don't think there is any issue with code. Because when Javascript function runs fine. When it tries to load the View i.e. html file it looks for myapp-web/view/AdminHome.html. But because the URL is changed, server sends 500 error.